# validate a textbox that Doesn't Start or End With Special Character

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I have some requirements that I need to implement a text box that doesn't allow special character at starting and ending of the string but it has option to allow in middle of the word
example:
***1)Some_@thing --True
2)_#2someThing --False
3)something_*@ --false***

```js
$(function () {
$('#text').on("change", function (e) {
if (this.value.match(/^[a-z0-9](?!.*?[^\na-z0-9]{100}).*?[a-z0-9]$/)) {
this.value = this.value.replace(/^[a-z0-9](?!.*?[^\na-z0-9]{100}).*?[a-z0-9]$/, '');
$("#eror").text("Accepts only Alphabets");
                   
                }   
         });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try pattern something like this `^[a-z0-9](?!.*?[^\na-z0-9]{100}).*?[a-z0-9]$`

Here is the [**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/z6wroR/1) of it. you can check it. 
 There's some error in your code too, here i had created one new fiddle. according to that you can modify your code. and it may work.

1> change your function to `.change` as i used in fiddle

2> compare pattern to string such like `pattern.test(string)`.

[**New Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/yashsoni789/ay1k3ywt/) with Working Pattern.
 hope so above solution work for you.

Comment: it is working in reverse i dont want to allow at starting and ending the special characters and even its not allowing alphabets

Comment: @Lier, can you give me a one string which is not working in demo, you can try your own string in Test String part, so i get a better idea what you actually want

Comment: it is working in demo but not in my environment   if (this.value.match(/^[a-z0-9](?!.*?[^\na-z0-9]{100}).*?[a-z0-9]$/)) {
                     this.value = this.value.replace(/^[a-z0-9](?!.*?[^\na-z0-9]{100}).*?[a-z0-9]$/, '');

Comment: can you put working demo of js snippet in your question posted with html code.

Comment: @Lier, after so much effort , i'm able to solve your problem, look into new fiddle and in which i have given jquery.min,js link as external resource.

Comment: Really great the mistake i am doing is replacing the pattern with empty in my code

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be looking for the reverse of what yash posted, screening for instances that break the rule, rather than conform to it.

Your 'if' conditional appears to be looking for a result that returns true if the special-character rule has been broken, so you would probably want something along the lines of:

```
//allows only letters and numbers at the start and end
/^[\W_\s].*$|^.*[\W_\s]$/

//allows only letters (and not numbers) at the start and end
/^[^A-Za-z_\s].*$|^.*[^A-Za-z_\s]$/
```

Both will allow special characters within the string itself, outside of the starting and ending characters, without triggering your boolean, but will trigger it if the strings starts or ends with those same characters.

As a side note, if you are only interested in testing for a regex match, and not with actually returning the regex matches, you should use:

```
regex.test('string')

//instead of
string.match(/regex/)
```

`match` is overkill for your needs here and will only slow down your application. `test` returns its result directly in boolean form and does so much quicker than `match`.

[MDN Section on using 'test'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)
(if you are interested in learning more about this specific use case)